# How to solve Read s.ytimg.com message in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, youtube

I have this message in the bottom left corner of Firefox 17:

```
Read s.ytimg.com
```

When trying to point it by mouse - the message run to the bottom-right corner - and vice versa.
I found on Google that I need turn off an option on YouTube (right click on playing video - Settings - Allow ytimg... - and I checked Denied.
But the message is still in Firefox.
How can i solve this, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the *actual* problem you're facing, besides simply seeing that message? ytimg.com is the **Y**ou**T**ube **IM**a**G**e server, and it is used to serve up the various image elements required by YouTube, including the player's "skin":

[image: 1]

Right-click any YT video and set the privacy settings for Adobe Flash Player to **Deny** and ensure **Remember** is checked:

[image: 2]

If you have problems playing back YT videos, let us know. You can also try `Help / Restart with Add-ons Disabled` to see whether any of your add-ons is the cause.

Comment: ThankYou, Karan, I didn't check `remember` checkmark. Thanks for your illustrated answer.